# The type javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, java-11

I am using Eclipse 4.13 and JDK 11. For my source code, it's giving this error *"type javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"* ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKiBF.png)) even when that package is available in JDK 11. Please guide.

Comment: No, this package is not available in JDK 11 anymore (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/module-summary.html#packages.summary)) and has to be added as dependency: https://www.studytonight.com/post/solved-caused-by-javalangclassnotfoundexception-javaxxmlwswebservicefeature-in-java-11

Comment: See [JEP 320](https://openjdk.org/jeps/320).